# #1064 error while deleting duplicate rows in wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to delete duplicate rows from wordpress tables and I'm getting sql error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a, wp_posts b WHERE a.ID > b.ID AND a.post_title = b.post_title' at line 1
```

like this
and My query is

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts a, wp_posts b WHERE a.ID > b.ID AND a.post_title = b.post_title
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Delete does Alias in a different way.

```
DELETE FROM a USING wp_posts a, wp_posts b 
WHERE a.ID > b.ID AND a.post_title = b.post_title
```

see [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12811) for more information

Answer (score 0):

feeling guilty to answer my question. Anyway I found an error,

My query should be,

```
DELETE a FROM  wp_posts a, wp_posts b WHERE a.ID > b.ID AND a.post_title = b.post_title;
```

like this.